# Android and Google Analytics: Cant track events

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in my projec and I am getting the "Problem with socket or streams." error message.

```
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416): Problem with socket or streams.
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416): java.net.SocketException: Host is unresolved: www.google-analytics.com
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:966)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PipelinedRequester.maybeOpenConnection(Unknown Source)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PipelinedRequester.addRequest(Unknown Source)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.NetworkDispatcher$DispatcherThread$AsyncDispatchTask.dispatchSomePendingHits(Unknown Source)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at com.google.android.apps.analytics.NetworkDispatcher$DispatcherThread$AsyncDispatchTask.run(Unknown Source)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(416):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Do you have any experience with this?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the code I am using:

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.startNewSession("xxxxxxxxxxxxx",context);
tracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");
tracker.dispatch();
```

Comment: post the code that you are using that results in this error.

Comment: do you have the Internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I am getting some other data from other servers and everything works fine.

Comment: Apparently, there are some problems with Google Analytics at the moment.

Comment: @Milos I see no problems with Analytics http://www.google.com/analytics/status#hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my custom rom. In some custom ROMs, in order to increase the battery life, the developpers are changing the localhost ip address. With this change, some services ie. Google Analytics are disabled and no data are uploaded automaticaly. As we know, more than 90% of the apps are using Google Analytics, so this will do the job: prevent data transfer and increase the battery life.

Comment: This is not really an issue. As described, some custom rom's are simply blocking google analytics. That means that if some users of your app are using custom roms, you can't track them.